# Replacing a number ended in dot at the beginning of the line with '.IP number\n'

Tags: linux, sed, freebsd

I want to replace numbers followed by period at the beginning of the line:

```
1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
12. The slow grey cat jumps over the lazy dog
234. The strong yellow lion jumps over the lazy dog
```

with `.IP number\ntext`, so the above input would lead to:

```
.IP 1
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
.IP 12
The slow grey cat jumps over the lazy dog
.IP 234
The strong yellow lion jumps over the lazy dog
```

I am using FreeBSD12.1 sed. I would prefer if solution might be reasonablily portable to Linux boxes.

This is what I have tried:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\)1\./\.IP \1\
/'
```

Comment: First shot: `sed -n 's/\([0-9\.]\)* \(.*\)/\.IP 1\n\2/p' file`.  You could also match the beginning of the line using the caret `^` as in  `sed -n 's/^\..... file`

Answer (score 1):

The following works on BSD sed.

```
sed -n 's/^\([0-9]*\.*\) \(.*\).*/.IP \1\n\2/p' filename`
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally did this:

```
cat /tmp/f6 | sed -E 's/^([[:digit:]])\. /\.IP \1\
/' > /tmp/f7
```